# Помогите написать MySQL запрос к трём таблицам, с выборкой по максимальной дате

Tags: mysql

Имеются 3 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `workname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `markedflag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 CREATE TABLE `price` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `item_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `doc_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `doc` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `code` int(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `docdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `apply` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

- в item находится продукция привязанная к определённому пользователю через user_id;
- в doc находятся записи (документы) которые тоже привязаны к пользователю через user_id и имеют дату создания docdate;
- в price находится сама цена которая связана с продукцией через item_id и связана с документом через doc_id;

Через создание нового документа обновляется цена у продукции, обновиться может как вся продукция так и всего одна позиция.
Из всего этого нужно получить список всей продукции для определённого пользователя с последними ценами.
В итоге должна получится табличка `item.id`, `price.price`, `doc.id`, `doc.docdate`

Заранее спасибо всем кто поможет :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Осмыслив запросы **Elfilagas** и **Александр Муксимов** составил такой запрос, он работает как нужно, но кажется что он далеко не оптимален :) ... поэтому всё ещё надеюсь что кто-то подскажет вариант лучше.

```
SELECT 
    nm.`id`, if(T2.`doc_id` is not null,T2.`doc_id`,'н/д') as `doc_id`, if(T2.`price` is not null,T2.`price`,'н/д') as `price`, if(T2.`docdate` is not null,T2.`docdate`,'н/д') as `docdate`
FROM
    `item` nm
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
    i.`id`, np.`price`, np.`doc_id`, dc.`docdate`
FROM
    `item` i,
    `price` np,
    `doc` dc
WHERE
    i.`user_id` = '1111111111' AND
    np.`item_id` = i.`id` AND
    np.`doc_id` = (SELECT d.`id`
        FROM
            `doc` d, `price` n
        WHERE
            d.`user_id` = i.`user_id` and n.`item_id` = i.`id` and n.`doc_id` = d.`id`
        ORDER BY d.`docdate` DESC
        LIMIT 1) AND
        dc.`id` = np.`doc_id`) AS T2 ON T2.`id` = nm.`id`
WHERE
    nm.`user_id` = '1111111111'
```

Comment: Ну если Вы смогли воспользоваться моей заготовкой, то добавьте мне рейтинга :), нажав на серую стрелочку вверх или проголосовав за мой вопрос, который Вы найдете в моем профиле.

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, что-то такое нужно?

```
select i.id, p.price, d.id, d.docdate from item i 
inner join price p on (i.id = p.item_id)
inner join doc d on (d.user_id = i.user_id) and (d.id = p.doc_id)
where d.id in (select id from doc where user_id = 'Сюда id юзера' group by id having max(docdate) > 1)
```

Comment: Почему не `where a.user_id = `?

Comment: Прикол в том, что если не выносить в where, выберутся все строки из item  и price, даже не относящиеся к юзеру. И я бы добавил inner к join

Comment: А я бы изменил псевдонимы на более осмысленные, `a/b/c` никуда не годятся) `i/p/d` гораздо легче воспримутся.

Comment: Согласен, есть куда расти. ) Исправил.

Comment: в строке с `inner join doc d on (d.user_id = i.user_id)` нужно ещё добавить `d.id = p.doc_id` тогда запрос работает корректно, но не совсем как нужно :) ... он выбирает из документов все цены, а нужна только актуальная (последняя) цена ... нужно взять id товара, посмотреть в каких документах он присутствует и взять цену из документа с самой последней датой

Comment: @Interruption Поправил, попробуйте.

Comment: запрос по прежнему выводит все цены для товара вместо одной самой новой

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вот такой запрос работает и выдают правильный результат

```
SELECT p.[item_id]
  ,p.[doc_id]
  ,p.[price]
  ,d.docdate 
FROM [price] p, [doc] d 
where d.Id = p.[doc_id] 
AND p.[doc_id] in (SELECT TOP 1 [Id] FROM [doc]  WHERE [user_id] = @user_id ORDER BY docdate] ASC )
```

Это лишь стартовая точка. Этот запрос будет выполняться в любом стандарте SQL (я его проверил), но Вам его нужно привести к привычной форме (Iner Join) для MySql, которого у меня нет сейчас под рукой.

Comment: к сожалению моих знаний не достаточно чтоб перевести ваш код в MySQL , на сколько я понял в подзапросе вы просто вытаскиваете id самого нового документа у конкретного пользователя, а как я писал в комментариях ранее ...  ... нужно взять id товара, посмотреть в каких документах он присутствует и взять цену из документа с самой последней датой

Comment: @Interruption, блина - блина, я не верно понял Вашу задачу - Вам нужно получить не последнее обновление для пользователя, а обновление для всех товаров, тогда без Max(Date) и Having с группировкой по товарам не обойтись, так что мою заготовку нужно переделывать. Я постараюсь это сделать, но смогу этим заняться только завтра утром